# Why phpMyAdmin file size limit is not changing?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm using WAMP Server and here trying to upload a sql file with the file size of 131 MB.

The current limit is showing 128MiB on phpMyAdmin upload screen.

But my php.ini configuration was:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
post_max_size = 2M
```

That was a bit awkward to me. But then, I changed them to:

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
```

And still it's showing (Max: 128MiB) limit.

The file I'm editing is in *"C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\"* directory and I did restarted the server after changing those values.

I found a workaround of this issue by typing mysql commands in cmd.
But my question is, why it's not reflecting my changes here?

Comment: Doesn't WAMP use more than one php.ini file? I think it has a couple of them scattered around somewhere. Are you sure you changed the right file?

Comment: It will anywhere overload your php.ini value

Comment: @TerrySeidler, there is another file named *phpForApache.ini*. I tried on that one too, but no luck.

Comment: Apparently the way to find the right php.ini is "The good one is Wampmanager Icon->PHP->php.ini"

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,133520

Comment: Yes, that's the file I'm using which is inside *C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\* directory.

Comment: `phpInfo()` shows the 'loaded initiialization file'.

Comment: `a workaround of this issue by typing mysql commands in cmd` it's a good idea to make that your standard means of administering a db.

Comment: I did that and it works. But some of my tables like `wp_user` were not showing. What could be the issue on that case? @AD7six

Comment: Not having permissions - but that's a different question. If you want an answer to _that_ question please ask a new question with appropriate details (like, what you did, what you see and what you expected to see).

Comment: did you restart your apache service via wamp?

Answer (score 48):

I have finally found out how to do that. PhpMyAdmin has its own settings here

C:\wamp64\alias\phpmyadmin.conf

1. now you just change

   ```
       php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 512M
       php_admin_value post_max_size 512M
       php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
       php_admin_value max_input_time 360
   ```
2. restart All services in Wamp
3. enjoy your day

Comment: Along with editing the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in the php.ini as well this is a lifesaver in WAMP!!! Thank you!

Comment: This is the only good answer and should be the accepted one, regardless of any PHP.INI file you might be changing, this directory directive will have the last word!!

Comment: Bless you! I have been looking everywhere for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

With WAMP, you need to modify the variable upload_max_filesize in the php.ini files of PHP and Apache, which are located under :

- C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\
- C:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.X

Comment: I did on those both files.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the value in this file:

```
wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf
```

Why they buried this configuration here among also having seperate php.ini files is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the default value for file upload in php. Example: form where you upload files. The default max for php is 2mb and if you want more you have to change it in php.ini where you did.
To change the phpmyadmin file size maybe in the config of the phpmyadmin but if the file is so large maybe try to upload other way no?

Comment: I don't think phpMyAdmin config can do the job here, but if you know the exact way please share.

Comment: I dont know the way to do it in phpmyadmin but with a file that large I use bigdump.php (http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) to do the job right.